# React Native FlatList Rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to RN and i have some issue with rendering items from API with flatlist. I use pagination from server to return 10 items per request and loadMore function for changing page and retrive new data. The problem is when i scroll few times(4-5 pages) i get this error and i'm confused how to fix it! I will be very thankful if someone can provide me fix. Thanks in advance! [image]

here is my API fetch function =>

```
    export const fetchProducts = (page) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchingFromServer());
    try {
      await fetch(SITE_URL + products + `&page=${page}` + '&per_page=12' + AUTH_PARAMS)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => dispatch(fetchingProductsSuccess(json)));
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch(fetchinProductsFailed(err));
    }
  };
};
```

here is my flatList =>

```
   <FlatList
              data={data || []}
              numColumns={2}
              maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
                return `${item.name}-${index}`;
              }}
              renderItem={({ item }) => {
                return this._renderItem(item);
              }}
              onEndReached={() => this.loadMoreData()}
              onEndReachedThreshold={2}
              ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter.bind(this)}
            />
```

here is render item function =>

```
_renderItem(item) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.containerP}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: item.images[0].woocommerce_thumbnail }} />
        <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.name}>
          {item.name}
        </Text>
        {item.regular_price !== '' && item.price + '' !== item.regular_price + '' ? (
          <View style={styles.prices}>
            <Text style={styles.price_discounted}>{item.regular_price}лв</Text>
            <Text style={styles.price}>{item.price}лв</Text>
          </View>
        ) : (
          <Text style={styles.price}>{item.price}лв</Text>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

and loadMore function =>

```
  loadMoreData() {
    const { fetching_from_server, isListEnd } = this.state;
    if (!fetching_from_server && !isListEnd) {
      this.setState({ fetching_from_server: true }, () => {
        this.props.productActions.fetchProducts(this.page);
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some of your items are missing images. Try adding a check to make sure an image exists for each item. Something like this should work:

```
_renderItem(item) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.containerP}>
      {item.images && item.images.length ? (
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={{uri: item.images[0].woocommerce_thumbnail}}
        />
      ) : null}

      <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.name}>
        {item.name}
      </Text>
      {item.regular_price !== '' &&
      item.price + '' !== item.regular_price + '' ? (
        <View style={styles.prices}>
          <Text style={styles.price_discounted}>{item.regular_price}лв</Text>
          <Text style={styles.price}>{item.price}лв</Text>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <Text style={styles.price}>{item.price}лв</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

To explain the error you are seeing a little further. `item.images` is expected to be an array of objects but if there are no images then `item.images[0]` will be undefined. You then try access the object property `woocommerce_thumbnail` but `item.images[0]` is undefined so you get the "undefined is not an object" error.

Comment: Thanks! I found the problems was that in my fetch function, i forgot to add &status=publish , and so the api fetch products in draft and so from there was the problem.

Comment: @KirilBehov No problem. That makes sense since some of the unpublished items might not have images yet. Would you mind accepting my answer if it helped solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, seems that your `item` in `_renderItem` is `undefined` (error says "undefined is not an object"). So you can easly solved by doing something like:

```
_renderItem(item) {
    return (
      {item &&
      <View style={styles.containerP}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: item.images[0].woocommerce_thumbnail }} />
        <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.name}>
          {item.name}
        </Text>
        {item.regular_price !== '' && item.price + '' !== item.regular_price + '' ? (
          <View style={styles.prices}>
            <Text style={styles.price_discounted}>{item.regular_price}лв</Text>
            <Text style={styles.price}>{item.price}лв</Text>
          </View>
        ) : (
          <Text style={styles.price}>{item.price}лв</Text>
        )}
      </View>}
    );
  }
```

Comment: It's possible that `item` is undefined but I would say it's much more likely that `item.images[0]` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The problem was with the query request to the API,  i forget to add &status=publish param to the query and so i fetch product from woocommerce which are in draft and have no images.